# How to get key string in dict python?

Tags: python

```
a = [{'dogcat': 0}, {'ratduck': 1}] 
for i in a:
  for k,v in i.item():
     print (k[0],v)
d 0
r 0
```

I want keep the first word is dog 0 rat 1

Comment: Why do you have a list around single item dictionaries?

Comment: Please explain why the expected output is `dog 0 rat 1` and not `dogcat 0 ratduck 1`. Do you want to keep only first letters ?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is printing `k[0]` which means the first character of the key. Use `k` instead if you want to see the whole key or `k[:3]` for just the first 3 characters, as in *dog*. Also, the method is called `items()` not `item()`.

Answer (score 0):

1). If you want to print only the part of a string of key then use the code given below:-

```
a = [{'dogcat': 0}, {'ratduck': 1}] 
for i in a:
    for k,v in i.items():
        print (k[:3],v )
```

2). The Output of the above code will be:-
 dog 0
 rat 1
3). Here I am applying the concept of indexing and slicing. You can learn indexing and slicing from   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_IySULAqE_k

Answer (score 0):

`items()` return the key-value pairs of the dictionary, look [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary-items-method/) for further information about how to use this method with examples

```
a = [{'dogcat': 0}, {'ratduck': 1}] 
for i in a:
    for k,v in i.items():
        print(k, v)
```

I think that you want the full key to be printed, if that's not the case you then can use print(k[0], v) were you will display only the first character of each key.